# android returning a "live" object from an AIDL bound service

Tags: android, android-service, ipc, aidl

I'd like to create an AIDL service that returns, for lack of the correct terminology, "live" objects. that is, I would like something like this to work,

```
IFoo foo = myService.getFoo(x); // calls to myService service to get an IFoo
IBar bar = foo.getBar(y); // IPC to IFoo to get an IBar
IBaz baz = bar.getBaz(z); // IPC to IBar to get an IBaz

baz.setEnabled(false); // IPC to IBaz to modify the service's copy of IBaz
```

I expect this to be possible, but I can find a good example. The alternative is to do something like,

```
myService.setBazEnabled(x, y, z, false);
```

the former being a more OO approach, while the latter is more functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as `IFoo`, `IBar`, and `IBaz` are all defined via AIDL, that should work just fine.

Comment: by "defined via AIDL", you mean i have an .aidl interface for them ... then i just return an object that implements that interface? would the object need to be `Parcelable`? only if it contains data in addition to methods?

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman: "you mean i have an .aidl interface for them" -- yes. "then i just return an object that implements that interface?" -- no, you subclass the `.Stub`, just as you do with your binder. "would the object need to be Parcelable?" -- no, and, in fact, I doubt that works. "only if it contains data in addition to methods?"  -- the data isn't moving. AIDL exposes methods. Basically, it's the difference between sending pure data over the network (e.g., REST Web service) and sending pure behavior over the network (e.g., SOAP Web service).

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman: I don't have an example of your scenario, but I do have a related one: callbacks. For your client to supply a callback object to the service, you define the callback AIDL, have the client implement the `.Stub`, and pass an instance of that `.Stub` to some method on the binder that accepts an instance of the callback. The service gets an instance of the AIDL-defined interface and can call methods on it. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AdvServices/RemoteClientEx and https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AdvServices/RemoteServiceEx

Comment: indeed, your suggestion in the second comment works. i will edit your answer to provide a clear example. "the data isn't moving. AIDL exposes methods."- that's a key point. you either return operations or data, but not both.

Comment: err, posted a new answer so as not to corrupt your post.

Answer (score 0):

Providing a clear example of the suggestion in comment #2 from CommonsWare ...

first, define sub-AIDL interfaces to be returned from the main AIDL interface,

```
interface IMyService {
  IFoo getFoo();
}
```

`IFoo` should itself be an AIDL interface,

```
interface IFoo {
  ...
}
```

in your implementation of `IMyService.getFoo()`, construct a new binder, and return that, as an `IFoo` interface,

```
public class MyService implements Service {
  public class FooBinder extends IFoo.Stub {
    ...
  }

  public class MyBinder extends IMyService.Stub {
    @Override
    public IFoo getFoo() {
      return IFoo.Stub.asInterface(new FooBinder()); 
    }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind() {
    return new MyBinder();
  }
}
```

Comment: You should just be able to return `new FooBinder()`, without the `IFoo.Stub.asInterface()`. In fact, I would expect `IFoo.Stub.asInterface()` to cause problems.

Comment: Neither  `IFoo.Stub.asInterface(new FooBinder());` nor  `new FooBinder()` works properly. When call the method in the `IFoo `, will got a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Format specifier: s` error from the `at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1624)`